# keras fit_generator reading chunks from hdfstore

Tags: keras, hdfstore

I try to build a generator for a Keras model which will be trained on a large hdf store. 
To speed up the training, I pre-calculated all features incl. one-hot encoding already in the hdfstore. So the call from that should be straight forward.

To feed chunks of my data into the network, I try to use fit_generator, but struggle to get it up and running.

The generator:

```py
def myGenerator(myStore, generateFrom,generateTo):
 # Create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels#
    while True:
        X = pd.read_hdf(myStore,'X',start=generateFrom,stop=generateTo)
        y = pd.read_hdf(myStore,'y',start=generateFrom,stop=generateTo)
        yield X,y
```

Network and fitting:

```py
def get_model(shape):
    '''Create a keras model.'''
    inputlayer = Input(shape=shape)

    model = BatchNormalization()(inputlayer)
    model = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(model)
    model = Dropout(0.25)(model)
    model = BatchNormalization()(inputlayer)
    model = Dense(512, activation='relu')(model)
    model = Dropout(0.25)(model)
    model = BatchNormalization()(inputlayer)
    model = Dense(256, activation='relu')(model)
    model = Dropout(0.25)(model)
    model = BatchNormalization()(inputlayer)
    model = Dense(128, activation='relu')(model)
    model = Dropout(0.25)(model)

    # 11 because background noise has been taken out
    model = Dense(2, activation='tanh')(model)

    model = Model(inputs=inputlayer, outputs=model)

    return model
shape = (6603,10000)
model = get_model(shape)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
#X = generator(myStore)
#Xt = generator(myStore)
labelbinarizer = LabelBinarizer()
y = labelbinarizer.fit_transform(y)
#yt = labelbinarizer.fit_transform(yt)

generateFrom = 0
for i in range(10):
    generateTo=generateFrom+10000
    model.fit_generator(
        generator=myGenerator(myStore,generateFrom,generateTo),
        epochs=1,
        steps_per_epoch=X[0].shape[0] // 1000)
    generateFrom=generateTo
```

I have tried both, to have the fit_generator within a loop and plug in the range (as shown above), but also to handle the range inside the generator. Both does not work. Currently running into

```py
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Likely I have some misunderstanding how fit_generator() is supposed to be used in this context. Most examples out there are around generating tensors from pictures.

Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function read_hdf returns a panda object, you need to convert it to numpy array.

Comment: Thanks, will add .as_matrix() to try. But else, the approach taken is right / best practice?